# Python PIL image compare issue

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to compare 2 images using PIL and the below is my scenario.

img1:

[image: img1]

img2:

[image: img2]

```
img1 = Image.open(img1.png)
img2 = Image.open(img2.png)
```

I have written a simple diff function which will return -1 if there is a difference or 0 if they are same.

```
def diff(img1, img2):
    im1 = img1.load()
    im2 = img2.load()

    for i in range(0, img1.size[0]):
        for j in range(0, img1.size[1]):
            if(im1[i,j] != im2[i,j]):
                return -1
    return 0
```

I am passing the following:

```
diff(img2, img1.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT))
```

Both are exactly the same image but I get a difference. The difference seems to be at:
[27 84]
Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: Looks as they are not exactly the same, at least the png ones do not seem to be aligned in height. Dump them as byte stream or check them with an image toolkit.

Comment: Thanks, it looked same to a naked eye but actually there seems to be a difference.

Comment: I am running into this issue right now. What did you end up doing to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to KBAI. So I ended up using a similarity ratio and not just do a exact pixel by pixel comparison.

Answer (score 10):

"Both are exactly the same image but I get a difference."

But they're not.

You can see this, using the code below for example:

```
def show_diff(img1, img2):
    diff = Image.new("RGB", img1.size, (255,255,255))
    for x1 in range(img1.size[0]):
        for y1 in range(img1.size[1]):
            x2 = img1.size[0] - 1 - x1
            y2 = img1.size[1] - 1 - y1

            if img1.getpixel((x1,y1)) != img2.getpixel((x2,y2)):
                print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
                diff.putpixel((x1,y1), (255,0,0))

    diff.show()

img_r = Image.open("img/pacman-r.png")
img_l = Image.open("img/pacman-l.png")
show_diff(img_r, img_l)
```

Which results in

[image: diff]

(Here, any pixel that differs between the two images is colored red.)

Or with

```
def show_delta(img1, img2):
    diff = Image.new("RGB", img1.size, (255,255,255))
    for x1 in range(img1.size[0]):
        for y1 in range(img1.size[1]):
            x2 = img1.size[0] - 1 - x1
            y2 = img1.size[1] - 1 - y1

            p1 = img1.getpixel((x1,y1))
            p2 = img2.getpixel((x2,y2))
            p3 = round((p1[0] / 2) - (p2[0] / 2)) + 128

            diff.putpixel((x1,y1), (p3,p3,p3))

    diff.show()

img_r = Image.open("img/pacman-r.png")
img_l = Image.open("img/pacman-l.png")
show_delta(img_r, img_l)
```

which results in

[image: delta]

(Here, equivalent pixels are gray while a white pixel signifies a pixel in img1 was set (dark) while unset in img2 and a black pixel signifies the opposite.)

It seems like you suspected that PIL's [`Image.transpose`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transpose) method caused the problem, but the source images aren't *just* transposed.

`Image.transpose` works as you'd expect -- so something like:

```
def diff(img1, img2):
    im1 = img1.load()
    im2 = img2.load()

    images_match = True
    for i in range(0, img1.size[0]):
        for j in range(0, img1.size[1]):
            if(im1[i,j] != im2[i,j]):
                images_match = False

    return images_match

img_r = Image.open("img/pacman-r.png")    
# NOTE: **NOT** Using img_l here
print(diff(img_r, img_r.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)))
```

returns `True`.

(Here, an image is compared to a twice-transposed version of itself)

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me think over your analysis and try to understand.